# errror in sending data to server using json object

Tags: android, json

i want to send some data to server on a specific url in json format but is not working. my json format is

```
  JSON Object﹕ {"appt_email":"grddgf@ffgh.com","appt_service":"Test services 11","appt_contact":"8554688564","appt_time":"18.44","appt_name":"fddvnhff","appt_date":"18\/9\/2015"}
```

i am using Chrome Poster extension to test it. when i use it the data is sent properly. bt when i send from application it is not working.

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(

                    "http://tipseducation.com/system/eadmin/insertschedule/");

            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            //StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); httpRequest.setEntity(se); httpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");
            json.put("appt_name", ed_name);
            json.put("appt_email", ed_email);
            json.put("appt_contact", ed_contact);
            json.put("appt_date", ed_date);
            json.put("appt_time", ed_time);
            json.put("appt_service", ed_spinner);
}
```

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: data is not entered in the database

Comment: StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());   
 httpRequest.setEntity(se);
 httpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: debug and check what is happening.

Comment: i dont understand what is wrong

Comment: Regardless of your problem, consider switching to HttpUrlConnection: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use String Request.

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(type, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          //Valid Response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error message
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
             params.put("appt_name", ed_name);
             params.put("appt_email", ed_email);
             params.put("appt_contact", ed_contact);
             params.put("appt_date", ed_date);
             params.put("appt_time", ed_time);
             params.put("appt_service", ed_spinner);
          return params;
        }
    };
```